How to set delay/latency for output AudioMedia of pjsua2
I using pjsua2 for android kotlin,
I want to set delay for output audio media.
In pjsip, use pjmedia_mem_capture_create ,pjsua_conf_connect to connect connference with port.
But in android I cant use buffer to storage audiomedia data.
How to implement it to kotlin with pjsua2?
Kotlin:
            currentCall?.let { call ->
                var ci = call.info
                val cmiv = ci.media
                for (i in cmiv.indices) {
                    val cmi = cmiv[i]
                    if (cmi.type == pjmedia_type.PJMEDIA_TYPE_AUDIO &&
                        (cmi.status == pjsua_call_media_status.PJSUA_CALL_MEDIA_ACTIVE ||
                                cmi.status == pjsua_call_media_status.PJSUA_CALL_MEDIA_REMOTE_HOLD))
                    {
                        /* Connect ports */
                        try {
                            val rec = call.getAudioMedia(i)
                            val play = endpoint.audDevManager().playbackDevMedia
                            // endpoint.audDevManager().captureDevMedia.startTransmit(rec)
                            // ----> I want to delay output at playback
                            rec.startTransmit(play)
                            rec.delete()
                        } catch (e: Exception) {
                            Log.d(TAG,"Failed connecting media ports" + e.message)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

Thanks.
